# getting mysql field as blank although its there !

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent a hell lot of time on this bug and I can't find the error. I have a table in a mysql database name 'stories' with many fields, including 'sid','title' and 'content'. I am trying to access these fields using PHP:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT sid,title,content FROM stories WHERE (promoted=1 and published=1) ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 0,1");

$promoted_article=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$sid=$promoted_article[sid];

echo $sid;
```

Through phpmyadmin I've checked everything- 'sid' is an auto-increment field and so exists for every record. However '$sid' comes out to be null everywhere. I cannot understand the problem at all. Anyone has the slightest idea why this may be occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sid=$promoted_article[sid];`

PHP thinks `sid` is a constante, you should use apostrofs around it like this:
`$sid=$promoted_article['sid'];`

It probably has nothing to do with your query, unless this doesn't work ^

Answer (score 1):

```
$sid=$promoted_article['sid'];
```

You are missing the `'` for the index of the `$promoted_article` array

Comment: @aakash: Yes, it is. `sid` is a constant (most likely NOT defined in that script, so evaluating to blank/null. `'sid'` is a string. The only time you do NOT use single quotes on an array key is within a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Test you result by reading output of

```
print_r($promoted_article);
```

To find out if it is problem with query or with retrieving data from result set.